# how to filter duplicate and groupby in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Working on a report query against the below data. The expected return record is 200, because it has two different names. the ID 100 should be filtered out, because it is a duplicate record. In this case, do we have ONE query to achieve it ?

```
Class  name
100    john
100    john
200    peter
200    mary
300    alice
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't 300 returned?

Comment: because it has only one name under 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the desired results, it looks for any `Class` with at least 2 distinct names:

```
SELECT Class
FROM table1
GROUP BY Class
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
```

Output

```
Class
200
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eL1NA1sYFd11G1yvt8uBZP/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query-

```
select class from
tablename group by class having count(distinc name)=2
```

Answer (score -2):

*Try this out :*

SELECT Class FROM table1
GROUP BY Class
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1 ;

Comment: Why are you posting something that is an **exact** copy of another post? How does this add value?